# Access Dlookup Not Working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Dlookup formula in an Access query that I am using to return the rate to be used based on the payment date in the same query.

I have a separate query containing interest rates over different date ranges per the below.

[image]

For some reason the formula works but doesn't return the correct Interest Rates, it is just returning random incorrect rates from the interest rate query.

The formula I am using is

```
Interest Rate: DLookUp("[Rate]","Interest Rates Query","#" & Format([Payment Date],"dd-mm-yyyy") & "# between [Interest Rates Query]![Date From] And [Interest Rates Query]![Date To]")
```

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same query, try this:

```
DLookUp("[Rate]","[Interest Rates Query]","[Payment Date] Between [Date From] And [Date To]")
```

Edit:

If two queries, use:

```
Select 
    q1.*, q2.Rate
From
    q1, q2
Where
    q1.PaymentDate Between q2.DateFrom And q2.DateTo
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, I've just edited the question, they are actually in separate queries

Comment: Is it possible to represent the above in an expression as I have a number of other iif formulas built in various expressions etc in this query which makes the SQL very difficult to unravel? Thanks

Comment: Not just like that. But somehow, yes.